# Ports mapping after Hono deployment

Tags: eclipse-hono

I deployed hono-1.0.0 on K8S 1.13.10.  It appears successfully deployed as below:

[Result after using "Kubectl get svc"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxEYG.png)

But when I checked web console, I got

[Result listed in Cloud Web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIulz.png)

Some containers' ports have no been defined:

28443 -> https/TCP
8443 -> https/TCP

when I open "hono-service-device-registry-ext-svc.yaml", I got the following spec...

spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 28080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
    nodePort: 31080
  - name: https
    port: 28443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
    nodePort: 31443
  selector:

I am wondering whether "targetPort: https" should be assigned a specific port here?  Strange is the above diagram 1 has port 28443 - 31443.  But Diagram 2 has no such port mapping

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve, what your expected outcome is and what you are actually experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

More direct question:

My question is whether "target port" as below in the file of "hono-service-device-registry-ext-svc.yaml" need defined specific ports.

spec:

ports:

-- name: http

port: 28080

protocol: TCP

***targetPort: http***

nodePort: 31080

--name: https

```
port: 28443
```

protocol: TCP

***targetPort: https***

nodePort: 31443